# У меня проблема с Aiogram FSM. Проблема в том что мне нужно писать боту два раза, чтобы он переключил стейт на новый

Tags: python, aiogram

**Почему-то мне нужно писать боту два раза чтобы он переключился на след. состояние**

````
async def state1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Вы уверены что хотите начать тренировку? да/нет')
    await state.update_data(ans=message.text.lower())
    await reg.check_3.set()



@dp.message_handler(state=reg.check_3)
async def state4(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    ans = message.text.lower()
    if ans == 'да' or ans == 'yes' or ans == 'y':
        await state.update_data(ans=message.text.lower())
        await reg.check_2.set()
    else:
        await message.answer('Тренировка отменена.')
        await state.finish()```
````

Comment: Я так понимаю, что следующее состояние это reg.check_2

Comment: попробуйте закончить первое состояние `await state.finish()` потом переходите ко второму `await reg.check_2.set()`

Comment: Не помогает, если есть еще способы напишите пожалуйста буду очень рад <3

Answer (score 0):

await YOUR_STATE.next()

переход к следующему состоянию из класса FSM

Comment: Не помогает, если есть еще способы напишите пожалуйста буду очень рад <3